# Extract specific data from string using PHP

Tags: php

I get input from text box like this string

```
E1915265113280001191202190000001840000001976E
```

But I only want first 14 digits (`19152651132800`) and show them like this on web page

```
Number = 19152651132800
```

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: when user submit this string and click submits button then i only want to show first 14 digits of string on screen.

Comment: [`ltrim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) then [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Comment: please write code or give some example i'm beginner

Comment: Read The Fine Manual I linked you. This is how one can progress.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a freecode service. If you don't try, you won't fail, but you won't succeed neither.

Comment: thanks  executable  for answer

Answer (score 0):

You first need to extract numbers from the string using

`$digit = preg_replace( '/\D+/', '', $str );`

then you retreive the 14 first numbers of the result with `substr($digit, 0, 14);`.

```
$str = "E1915265113280001191202190000001840000001976E";
$result = substr(preg_replace( '/\D+/', '', $str ), 0, 14);
echo $result; // Output: 191526511328000
```

Comment: What's the point in asking what they tried if you're just going to do the work for them? Just a thought.